MS lists conditional formatting time
I am looking to see if we can conditionally format an MS lists column Date/Time but against the time setting i.e. if a time entered is >15minutes in comparison to another time in a column. is there a way of doing this.

Here is a sample JSON formatting that compare 15 minutes between two Date and Time fields.
15 minutes=900000 Milliseconds

if the [StartDateTime] is < [EndDateTime], 'red'

if [EndDateTime] within 15 minutes of [StartDateTime], 'green'

else 'orange'




{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(@currentField<[$StartDateTime],'red', if(@currentField <([$StartDateTime]+900000), 'green', 'orange'))",
    "font-size": "1.5em",
    "font-weight": "bold"
  }
}



